# onclick on both web and mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mobile, onclick

onclick function works on web browser, but not on mobile. 
I changed onclick to ontouchstart for mobile test, it did not work on mobile. 
Is there any way to use this code on both web and mobile browser?

```
...
<input type="submit" name="button" value="somevalue" onclick="return myFunction()">

<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction()
    {....
    }
</script>
...
```

Comment: Try onclick="if (myFunction())" to see if it works.

Comment: Would you like an answer using jquery or is that something you're not familiar with or using?

Comment: I tried  onclick="if (myFunction())" , but did not work.

Comment: This code belongs to a logon page of a project. I cannot change project codes, I can only change logon.aspx page. I think I cannot use jquery for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

`<input type="submit" name="button" value="somevalue" onclick="myFunction">`